# fade out the last word of paragraph

Tags: css, fadeout

[plz check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWdJu.jpg)

I need to `fade out` every last word in the 4th line of my post description. and when someone clicks on the post, it goes to the full description post page.

Comment: why don't you post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `overflow : hidden` CSS property.

watch this link for better understanding...............

[Click here](https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/)

Comment: This is not a solution for my problem